# Change Text in javaFX during another process, or before

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

```
    Text dirStatus = new Text();
    String mainPath = new String(); // path to finded dir
    Stage preStage = new Stage();

 public void preloader() throws IOException {

        File [] root = File.listRoots();
        Path startPath = root[0].toPath(); // find highest dir

        Group preGroup = new Group();

        dirStatus.setText("Press to start serch!");
        dirStatus.setLayoutX(20);
        dirStatus.setLayoutY(100);

        Button dirFind = new Button("Serch");
        dirFind.setLayoutX(180);
        dirFind.setLayoutY(150);


        preGroup.getChildren().add(dirStatus);
        preGroup.getChildren().add(dirFind);

        Scene preScene = new Scene(preGroup, 400, 200);
        preStage.setScene(preScene);
        preStage.show();


        dirFind.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                Title title = new Title();
                Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                title.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
                title.run();
                mainPath="";
                PrintFiles pf = new PrintFiles();
                try {
                    Files.walkFileTree(startPath, pf);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (mainPath!=""){
                    dirStatus.setText(dirStatus.getText() + "      Finded!!!");

                }
            }
        });




    }



    public class Title extends Thread {
        public Title(){

        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Started");
            dirStatus.setText("Serch in process...");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }


 public class PrintFiles extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {


        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) {
            if (dir.endsWith("HUP")){
                System.out.println("Finded");
                mainPath=""+ dir;
                System.out.println(mainPath);
                dirStatus.setText(mainPath);
                return FileVisitResult.TERMINATE;

            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }


        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
            System.err.println(exc);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    }

}
```

Hellow to everybody.
This is the part of my code and i try to make it better.

i need to change the field dirStatus to text: "Serch in process...", after mouse click on the button.

But in all cases, that i try, field dirStatus changed after finishing PrintFiles class serchig directory.

This is the last try with thread using. But it alsoow doesnt reach the goal.
Give me pls some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is totally wrong. You are "spawning" one more thread and you are trying to update JavaFX UI from that thread. Same as Swing or SWT, JavaFX is a singlethreaded UI toolkit and it's unsafe to update it outside of FX application thread (as you are doing with your `Text` component). In cases like these, use [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) utility class which is similar to `SwingWorker`. Run all background tasks on [call](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#call()) method. In your case, you can instantly change text of `dirStatus` `Text` to "Search in progress..." (in buttons `handle` method) and then start "Task". That way, your UI will remain responsive. And after task is done, you may remove "Search in progress..." from [succeeded](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#succeeded()) method (note that succeeded method runs in FX application thread so it's perfectly safe to update your `Text` from there).
You may read more about that [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm).

Comment: Thank you.
Yours answer is very helpfull for me.
I dont know anything about task method before.
Such method wasn t  the theme on my course.